# fineuploader S3 policy document variable to pass to web2py controller function

Tags: web2py, fine-uploader

I am trying to integrate fineuploader S3 into my web2py web application to allow uploads of large files.  I have got most of the code setup but I am encountering an issue with the policy document POST.

I need to locate the policy document JSON variable that is produced by fineuploader that is POSTed to the endpoint in order that I can attach it as an args variable.  This is because of the way web2py sends data to functions. (I was trying to use the django server example to help me understand what is going on but this sends variables to a function in a different way).

The code I currently have in my javascript is this:

```
    var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
element: document.getElementById("uploader"),
request: {
    endpoint: "https://XXXXXXXXX.s3-website-XXXXX-1.amazonaws.com",
    accessKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    params: {category: "XXX"}
},
debug: true,

signature: {
    endpoint: "{{=URL('upload', 'sign_policy_document',args=[request])}}"

},
uploadSuccess: {
    endpoint: "{{=URL('upload', 'success_redirect_endpoint')}}"
}
    });
```

I need to replace the 'request' in the args component with the variable that contains the JSON policy document created by fineuploader.  Then it will send it to my function where I can collect the arg and use the JSON to create the signature required.

I have tried searching the javascript for the variable created but I cannot figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what an "args component" or an "args variable" is. Fine Uploader includes the policy document for non-chunked uploads in the body of the request to your signature server. Other details can be found at http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html.

Comment: What I need to know is the variable that represents that Policy Document.  I appreciate that it is included in the body of the request, but there must be a variable that is created that contains that JSON formatted policy document.   It is that variable that I need to add as an 'args' (argument) variable for my function call to the web2py controller.  Thank you for the link, but I had seen this already and it doesn't give me enough information to solve the problem......as far as I can tell.

Comment: There is no such "variable". The policy document is not exposed via the API and is not accessible to external code. The only way currently to obtain the policy document is to parse the body of the signature request server side.

Comment: Ok.  I think I understand now.  I am just struggling to see how to parse the body of the signature request.  I will try a few things out and post back if I have any success.

Comment: What would really help me to understand how to implement this in web2py is if you can clarify for me what django view function is called by the signature endpoint and the upload success endpoints in the s3 django server side examples at: [link](https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/tree/master/python/django-fine-uploader-s3).  I just can't seem to figure out which ones are called.  I don't have any experience of Django and the HTML file that would tell me doesn't seem to be included in the example.